# With EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES make does not export variables with dot

Tags: makefile, cygwin, mingw

The following was tested with MinGW msys and with Cygwin.
When defining the phony target EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES in a makefile and then executing a sub-make, variables with dot are not exported.
So **CFLAGS** is exported but **CFLAGS.cpp** and **CFLAGS.c** are not.

Is this a documented feature? What is the rational?
Is there a way around it to export ALL variables?

Example:

**test1.mak**

```
CFLAGS=-O2
CFLAGS.cpp=-O2 -fno-rtti
all:
    $(MAKE) -f test2.mak
.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:
```

**test2.mak**

```
$(info CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)')
$(info CFLAGS.cpp='$(CFLAGS.cpp)')
all:
    @echo Done
```

**Output:**

```
make -f test1.mak 
CFLAGS='-O2'
CFLAGS.cpp=''
Done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables in POSIX sh cannot contain a "."; try it:

```
$ FOO.BAR=foobar
FOO.BAR=foobar: command not found
```

Make will only export variables which are valid to the shell.

The GNU make manual says:

```
If you use export by itself to export variables by
default, variables whose names contain characters other than
alphanumerics and underscores will not be exported unless specifically
mentioned in an export directive.
```

And then:

```
you can write a rule for the special target
.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES instead of using the export directive.
```

So, that target is the same thing as using `export` by itself, and has the same restrictions.

Comment: will be more helpful if you provide an example how to write a rule for the .EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` is a built-in pseudo-target: see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#index-_002eEXPORT_005fALL_005fVARIABLES  There's no need to write a rule for it, other than what's shown in the question already.